# Enable / Disable Add to Cart button programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I have added one text box for the zip codes on a products detail page. 
I want to keep "Add to cart" button disabled in starting. After any zip code is entered in the text box then only "Add To cart" button should get enabled. 
I want to know that how to make "Add to cart" button disabled in starting and how to make it enable via code.

Comment: You'll need to write some JS for this. Do you have anything you tried so far ?

Comment: Yes I have did it using cookies. If zip code is entered by user then I am storing it in a cookie. If that cookie is set then only I am displaying Add To Cart button.

Comment: Well, that seems like a fair option, what error you are facing in that ?

Comment: It is working. But I was not sure whether it is a right way to do it or not.